# Number of recursive calls in Recursive function analysis

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Reading algorithms by self using Robert Sedwick book in C++

> A recursive function that divides a problem of size N into two
>   independent (nonempty) parts that it solves recursively calls itself
>   less than N times.
>
> If the parts are one of size k and one of size N-k, then the total
>   number of recursive calls that we use is T(n) = T(k) + T(n-k) + 1, for
>   N>=1 with T(1) = 0.
>
> The solution T(N) = N-1 is immediate by induction. If the sizes sum to
>   a value less than N, the proof that the number of calls is less than
>   N-1 follows from same inductive argument.

My questions on above text are

1. How author came with solution T(N) = N-1 by induction? Please help me to understand.
2. What does author mean by "If the sizes sum to a value less than N, the proof that the number of calls is less than N-1 follows from same inductive argument" ?

I am new to mathematical induction so having difficulty in understanding.

Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) By induction:

```
T(1) = 0 (base)
T(N) = T(k) + T(N-k) + 1 (definition of problem)
```

We assume for each `n < N`, we get `T(n) = n-1`

Since both `k` and `N-k` are smaller then `N`, we get from the induction hypothesis:

```
T(N) = (k-1) + (N-k-1) + 1 = N-1
         ^        ^
        T(k)    T(N-k)
```

(2) 
Using the same argument:
if

```
T(N) = T(k) + T(m) + 1 where k+m < N
```

Then the same proof will lead to `T(N) < N-1`

Comment: Why in second case +1 is not added i.e., T(N) = T(k)+T(m)+1?

Comment: @venkysmarty: yes, it is a typing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, first I should mention that in my opinion author is wrong, because you have this recursion equation:

T(n) = T(k) + T(n-k) + 2 : because for n > 1 you called two smaller parts not one.
Now our assumption is 2(n-1) recursion call.

Now let check it with induction:

```
T(1) -> no recursive call.
T(2) = T(1) + T(1) + 2 : two recursive call.
...
T(n) = T(k) + T(n-k) + 2 = 2(k-1) + 2(n-k-1) + 2 = 2n-2 = 2(n-1).
```

Also for the second part of your question, author means if you divide into two parts such that sum of the part is smaller than n like part of size k and another part of size n-2k for k > 1.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we do not "came with the solution by induction", we use induction to prove our initial guess. Now, In order to guess we can use methods like Recursion tree.
In your problem, the worst case is for `k=1`, since it will results the most number of recursions. We also know the cost at each level :

```
T(n) = T(1) + T(n-1) + 1 => T(n) = T(n-1) + 1
```

Now we have to find the cost of `T(n-1)` and add that to cost `T(n)=1`.
We guess the final result is `N-1`. In this step we use induction to prove our guess.

**Update :**
Cost of T(n) is 1 ( T(1) is zero, plus T(n-1) that will be calculated, plus 1 => 1 ), cost of T(n-1) is also one ( with same logic ). We go down by depth of n-1. The last one is T(1) which is zero. ( draw a tree, it will help you to understand ).
This method to guess order of growth called [recursion tree](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2012sp/lectures/lec20-master/lec20.html). Now you can prove it by induction.

For more information about how to apply induction to prove the hypothesis, refer to text books like [CLRS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844).

Comment: why should we guess final result is N-1? And also I think you mean we add T(n-1)+1 to get T(n).