# Divide-and-conquer algorithms' property example

Tags: algorithm, recursion, divide-and-conquer

I'm having trouble with understanding the following property of divide-and-conquer algorithms.

> A recursive method that divides a problem of size `N` into two independent
>       (nonempty) parts that it solves recursively calls itself less than `N` times.

The proof is

> A recursive function that divides a problem of size `N` into two independent
>       (nonempty) parts that it solves recursively calls itself less than `N` times.
>       If the parts are one of size `k` and one of size `N-k`, then the total number of
>       recursive calls that we use is `T(n) = T(k) + T(n-k) + 1`, for `N>=1` with `T(1) = 0`.
>       The solution `T(N) = N-1` is immediate by induction. If the sizes sum to a value
>       less than `N`, the proof that the number of calls is less than `N-1` follows from
>       same inductive argument.

I perfectly understand the formal proof above. What I don't understand is how this property is connected to the examples that are usually used to demonstrate the divide-and-conquer idea, particularly to the finding the maximum problem:

```java
static double max(double a[], int l, int r) 
  { 
    if (l == r) return a[l]; 
    int m = (l+r)/2; 
    double u = max(a, l, m); 
    double v = max(a, m+1, r); 
    if (u > v) return u; else return v; 
  }
```

In this case when a consists of `N=2` elements `max(0,1)` will call itself 2 more times, that is `max(0,0)` and `max(1,1)`, which equals to `N`. If `N=4`, `max(0,3)` will call itself 2 times, and then each of the subsequent calls will also call max 2 times, so the total number of calls is `6 > N`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not missing anything. The theorem and its proof are wrong. The error is here:

```
T(n) = T(k) + T(n-k) + 1
```

The constant term of 1 should be 2, as the function makes one recursive call for each of the two pieces into which it divides the problem. The correct bound is 2N-1, rather than N. Hopefully, this error will be fixed in the next edition of your textbook, or at least in the errata.

Comment: Now I feel at ease-). I actually found in Robert Sedwick's Algorithms in Java. His C++ book has the same [error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264936/number-of-recursive-calls-in-recursive-function-analysis).